# What is the benefit of opening port 8333 to a client?

Tags: bitcoin-core, network, port

I am running a bitcoin core (v0.15.01) full node according to https://bitcoin.org/en/full-node. They say

> "To support the Bitcoin network, you also need to allow incoming
>   connections."

I hesitate opening ports because having a port open for incoming connection allows for anyone to connect. **So is this really necessary for bitcoin to work?** They to not explicitly state what kind of support this enables.

I see that the client already makes connections to various domains like

```
x9.dnsseed.bluematt.me
x9.seed.bitcoinstats.com
dnsseed.bitcoin.dashjr.org
x9.seed.bitcoin.sipa.be
x9.seed.btc.petertodd.org
x9.seed.bitcoin.jonasschnelli.ch
```

Do these represent the "distributed" properties of Bitcoin? Why are there not more of them? Or is this completely unrelated?

Note: I have read questions like [this one](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/40953/how-to-trigger-port-for-bitcoin-client-e-g-8333) or [this one](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/61546/what-is-the-nat-traversal-technique-used-by-bitcoin), but they more focus on the how to, than what the benefit actually is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't want to, you don't have to open ports at all. You'll still have a full node, it will just have fewer connections. Full nodes usually make 8 outgoing connections and can have many more incoming if you have the port open (for a total of 125 by default). Incoming connections can also be SPV (phone) wallets, or other full nodes.

So the benefit is that you're helping out the network a little bit more providing connection opportunities and bandwidth to more other full and non-full nodes. There's not really a shortage at the moment though.

Typically only the first time when you run the software it might do a DNS lookup on the domains you mention. Each name represents dozens of IP addresses of random other full nodes (not just nodes run by those people). Once your node has a connection to a few peers, it will learn new IP addresses from those, maintaining its own list of IP addresses which is stored when you close the software shuts down.